# Why does my jQuery menu disappear before I click a link?

Tags: jquery

I am writing a jQuery dropdown menu.  I hover over a link and a menu is supposed to appear... and does.  The problem is that the menu closes before I get to a menu link.  The menu should not disappear unless the mouse leaves the menu or the top level link.  Should I be doing this differently?

```
$(function(){
    //Find all ul elements within items in the nav
    $('nav ul li:has(ul)').each(function(){
        //Prevent the links that have submenus from being clicked
        $(this).children('a').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $(this).children('a').mouseover(function(){
            console.log('hovered');
            $(this).parent().find('ul').css('display', 'inline');
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('ul').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oypo3vrm/)

Comment: a fiddle would be nice

Comment: added to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `mouseover` id bound to the anchor element, and the ul is not a children of it, so when you move to the submenu it closes.

Change your selector to:

```
$(this).mouseover(function(){
    console.log('hovered');
    $(this).parent().find('ul').css('display', 'inline');
})
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').css('display', 'none');
});
```

and will work fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/oypo3vrm/1/

Answer (score 3):

Why jQuery ? When u can do it in pure CSS.

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:inline;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/oypo3vrm/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('nav ul li:has(ul)').each(function(){
        //Prevent the links that have submenus from being clicked
        $(this).children('a').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        //you don't need li in here
        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            console.log('hovered');
            $(this).parent().find('ul').css('display', 'inline');
        })
        .mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('ul').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
});
```